# How do I develop npm installed packages along with my app?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I'm working on my application. In parallel, I'm working on updating(and adding to) a couple of the npm installed submodules at the same time.

In my package.json dependencies I have:

```
"zeke-bootstrap": "git://github.com/twilson63/zeke-bootstrap.git",
```

When I do npm install, it goes and checks out the repository and puts it under node modules just fine. My question is how to I setup this directory so that I can use git, and do commits, and eventually a push to send my changes in my dependent directory back up to github?

Thanks,

Fred

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout your git repo in the `node_modules` folder under the same folder name as your module and node will automatically use it. However, I don't think its a very good idea. Modules are modules because they are meant to be developed separately.

Comment: In the case of zeke-bootstrap, I am extending the package as I develop my app.

Comment: If I just create a new directory, setup my git, and do the checkout, will npm update over the top and mess me up? Should I remove those modules from my package.json on my application?